# "X is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported." Where?

Tags: macos, sudo

"X is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported."

Where is it reported?

Comment: The same place as your "permanent record" from elementary school.

Comment: Probably here: http://xkcd.com/838/ ;)

Comment: @jb. Check the alt-text. It says where it is reported, though it uses the depreciated location to make it fit in the song structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **older** versions of OS X (through 10.6 or maybe 10.7), the disallowed sudo attempt would be logged in `/var/log/secure.log`; in more **recent** versions it's recorded in the ASL (Apple System Log) database, in `/var/log/asl/*`. You can read this with the `Console.app` utility (select ALL MESSAGES in the sidebar, then if you can't find them use the search field in the upper right to search for `sudo`). You can also use the command-line `syslog` command to query the database (`syslog -k Facility authpriv -k Sender sudo` should do it). Note that with either `Console.app` or `syslog`, the entries will only be visible if you are running as an admin or root.

Answer (score 4):

[Apparently Santa get the reports](http://xkcd.com/838/). On a serious mode:

> The event will be logged in /var/log/secure.log and a mail will be sent to root (which by default goes to /dev/null which is Unix speak for it is discarded).

Thanks to [patrix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/30004).

So, you can check the `/var/log/secure.log` file for all the events. `mail` isn't reliable because is redirected to the oblivion (anything that goes to `/dev/null` get lost)

Comment: I am unable to find that log file at that location on my Mavericks machine.

Comment: I can however find something under /var/log/module/com.apple.securityd/security.log.<datetime>

Comment: mm... I don't have a Mac... but the people that know (in [apple.se]) says that there is one... maybe they were lying...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember it could be viewed by command `mail`
But this was in Debian, dont know how it is in OSX